# How to extract title from this array in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have json object of thousand students I have converted that json object into array, this is how one array looks like

```
 [ 'Alex',
  { id: '0.0010733333111112',
    grade: 'N/A',
    street: 'N/A',
    zip: 'N/A',
    hobby: 'soccer' } ]
```

How can i extract name from array like in this Alex.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you created a bad data structure out of your json data. Why did you not put name in the object?

Comment: `whateverYourVariableIsCalled[0]` ... *I have json object* no, you have JSON or an object - JSON is a string, an object is an object

Comment: As Jaromanda said, get the index 0 of array.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by `YourArrayName[0]` **IF** you don't have all of your students' information in one array.

If that is the case, you would need to alter the structure of your array into key-value pairs. And call `Object.keys(YourArrayName)` to get all of the students' names.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an array and you are trying to get the first element.
To get items from an array use `nameOfMyArray[Index]`, in your case it would be `nameOfYourArray[0]` (remember that the first item is always 0).

```
var myStudent = [ 'Alex',
  { id: '0.0010733333111112',
    grade: 'N/A',
    street: 'N/A',
    zip: 'N/A',
    hobby: 'soccer' } ];
alert(myStudent[0])
```

And if you want to loop over your students list:

```
for (var i in myStudentList) {
  alert(myStudentList[i][0]);
}
```

It doesn't matter if your student were in a JSON because you said that you converted that JSON string into an array of students (were *I think* each item is like the student *Alex* of your example).

Finally I think it would be a better way to store your students as **key-value** (name and dictionariesof information) instead of your actual way *array of dictionaries* so your example would be:

```
 var myStudent = { 'Alex':
        {id: '0.0010733333111112',
        grade: 'N/A',
        street: 'N/A',
        zip: 'N/A',
        hobby: 'soccer'}
 }
```

And if you use that idea, to get the name of all the students do:

```
alert(myStudentList.Keys())
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an array with 2 things in it, namely a string at index 0 and an object at index 1. So, use bracket notation to get the item at index 0 like:

```js
var arr = [ 'Alex',
  { id: '0.0010733333111112',
    grade: 'N/A',
    street: 'N/A',
    zip: 'N/A',
    hobby: 'soccer' } ]
    
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Comment: this is how my object is structured in raw format could you please tell how I can extract from it  { 'Alex':
        {id: '0.0010733333111112',
        grade: 'N/A',
        street: 'N/A',
        zip: 'N/A',
        hobby: 'soccer'},
        { 'Alex':
                {id: '0.0010733333111112',
                grade: 'N/A',
                street: 'N/A',
                zip: 'N/A',
                hobby: 'soccer'}

Comment: you appear to have an array of objects so `myObject[0].Alex.grade`, or maybe `myObject[0].id`?

Comment: problem is that name or id wont be known prior, i will have a raw object and i have to get all the names of student from it.

Comment: {{ 'Alex':
        {id: '1',
        grade: 'N/A',
        street: 'N/A',
        zip: 'N/A',
        hobby: 'soccer'},
        { 'Bob':
                {id: '2',
                grade: 'N/A',
                street: 'N/A',
                zip: 'N/A',
                hobby: 'soccer'},
                { 'Jane':
                        {'3',
                        grade: 'N/A',
                        street: 'N/A',
                        zip: 'N/A',
                        hobby: 'soccer'} this is the exact structure of json object

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array `map()` method to fetch the `name` from each object in an array.

**DEMO**

```js
var arr = [{
 id: '0.0010733333111112',
 grade: 'N/A',
 street: 'N/A',
 zip: 'N/A',
 hobby: 'soccer',
 name: 'Alex'
}, {
 id: '0.0010733333111113',
 grade: 'N/A',
 street: 'N/A',
 zip: 'N/A',
 hobby: 'cricket',
 name: 'Bob'
}];

var newArr = arr.map(obj => {
  return obj.name;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: {{ 'Alex': {id: '1', grade: 'N/A', street: 'N/A', zip: 'N/A', hobby: 'soccer'}, { 'Bob': {id: '2', grade: 'N/A', street: 'N/A', zip: 'N/A', hobby: 'soccer'}, { 'Jane': {'3', grade: 'N/A', street: 'N/A', zip: 'N/A', hobby: 'soccer'} this is the exact structure of json object could you please tell me how i can get names if the names id or length of complete object is unknown thanks.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON